# Codeigniter table heading text wont center

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-table

I am having a problem with the table heading in my table created using table library of codeigniter, this is my table template:

```
$tmpl = array (
                'table_open'          => '<table style="align: center;" border="5" >',

                'heading_row_start'   => '<tr style="border: 2px solid black; background-color: #2ecc71; font-weight:bold; color:white; align:center;">',
                'heading_row_end'     => '</tr>',
                'heading_cell_start'  => '<th style="align:center;border: 2px solid black;" height=70 width=200>',
                'heading_cell_end'    => '</th>',

                'row_start'           => '<tr style="background-color: #DBF6ED; font-weight:bold;">',
                'row_end'             => '</tr>',
                'cell_start'          => '<td style="border: 2px solid black;" align=center height=50>',
                'cell_end'            => '</td>',

                'row_alt_start'       => '<tr style="background-color: white; font-weight:bold;">',
                'row_alt_end'         => '</tr>',
                'cell_alt_start'      => '<td style="border: 2px solid black;" align=center height=50>',
                'cell_alt_end'        => '</td>',

                'table_close'         => '</table>'
          );
```

and this is what it does in the table heading:

[image]

as you can see the text are not centered.

Comment: Try in your `style` `text-align:center`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `text-align: center;` instead of `align: center;`